# VS Code incomplete classpath even with a .classpath file

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am writing Java in VS code using the Language Support for Java by RedHat, and Remote - SSH extensions.

I'm importing an already existing project that has a `.classpath` file at the project root (this worked fine in IntelliJ). When I open the folder in visual studio, it tells me that the classpath is incomplete, even though the `.classpath` file exists and was good enough for IntelliJ.

How can I fix this?

Comment: could you show your `.classpath` file ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it contains code that is proprietary to my company. Given the fact it worked in IntelliJ, it seems likely the classpath is not the issue.

Comment: We need a sample classpath to reproduce the issue, could you please show a sample classpath that can repro the problem? Feel free to replace any sensitive informations with placeholders.